# Uploadify for ASP.NET app returns HTTP Error for large files

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

My Uploadify script works fine for most files less than 10 MB. But once the file size starts to exceed 40 MB, it will fail to upload with only an error message of "HTTP Error". I tried implementing the onError handler for Uploadify but it does not give me any details what the exact error is. The variable returns as "undefined". I checked my web.config file and the file size limit is set to 50 MB and I have a timeout of 30 minutes, so I'm at a loss as what the problem can be. Here is my script:

```
$('#uploader').uploadify({
  'uploader': '/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'script': '/cms/common/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx',
  'cancelImg': '/images/cancel_upload.png',
  'buttonImg': '/images/select_video_thumbnail_en-us.gif',
  'auto': true,
  'folder': '/Temp',
  'multi': false,
  'sizeLimit': 0,
  'displayData': 'percentage',
  'simUploadLimit': 1,
  'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
  'fileDesc': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
  'buttonText': 'Select thumbnail...',
  'width': '120',
  'height': '24',
  'onComplete': function (e, queueId, fileObj, response, data)
  {
    return true;
  },
  'onError': function (a, b, c, d)
  {
    if (d.status == 404)
      alert('Could not find upload script.');
    else if (d.type === "HTTP")
      alert('error ' + d.type + ": " + d.status);
    else if (d.type === "File Size")
      alert(c.name + ' ' + d.type + ' Limit: ' + Math.round(d.sizeLimit / 1024) + 'KB');
    else
      alert('error ' + d.type + ": " + d.text);
  },
  'onCancel': function (e, queueId, fileObj, data)
  {

  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what's going on ? My first thoughts would indeed be the maxRequestLength and RequestTimeout. By the way, 30 minutes timeout makes timeout useless, it's way too long ! (and are you sure it's not 30 seconds ?)

Comment: maxRequestLength = 50000, RequestTimeout= 30000. 30 minutes isn't unreasonable. I tried uploading a 40 MB file and it took nearly 12 minutes using DSL connection. Some users might have really slow speeds, so 30 minutes is playing it safe. Also, you need to include time for the system when its heavily used.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server?

Comment: The asp.net app runs on a remote server. The file is uploaded from my browser on my local computer.

Answer (score 3):

IIS7, which I am running, has a default internal file size limit of 30 MB. Setting maxRequestLength larger than this won't help. The problem is resolved by adding the following to your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This can also be set in IIS7. For more details, see the following links:
[IIS7 File Upload Size Limits](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits)
[Enabling Request Filtering In IIS 7](http://www.hosting.com/support/windows-server-2008/enabling-request-filtering-in-iis-7)

Answer (score 0):

Add following tag in your uploadify function.

```
'sizeLimit': '10045728'
```

It will work for you. size limit is your file size limit. It is in KB.